# Play Framework onStarup issue

Tags: playframework, akka

I have a Play server hosting a couple of WebSocket endpoints. What I want to do is that, during startup of my Play server, I want to initialize the default akka system that play is using. But what is happening right now is that I could only see that the default akka system is initialized when the first request to the WebSocket endpoint is made. How do I ask the Play framework to start the default akka system during startup?

Comment: This sounds like the behavior of dev mode (the server isn't actually started until the first request is made), as the Akka system is started before `onStart` is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have managed to do this as below:

1. Make a call to the Akka.system(app) in the onStartUp method defined in the Global controller
2. I added a ping WebSocket Endpoint
3. I created a batch script that would actually call the ping WebSocket after the server is started

With this I'm now able to initialize the entire Akka system before the first real request is made to my server.